# How to open registeration form on category click

Tags: magento2

**When Guest user click on any category it redirect to create account page.**

**How to achieve this ?**

*Please help me.*

Comment: means when user click on category it has to check is he logged in or no... if not then redirect to registration page?

Comment: yes exactly have you tried this

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Chikku please check my answer and update me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This Code and Event**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view">
       <observer name="go_to_login" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\LoginCheck" />
</event>
```

> **LoginCheck.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class LoginCheck implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            // your code
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/create');
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please find best event i will only give you idea here

Create an even `Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml`

```
<event name="catalog_category_view_load_before">
        <observer name="check_login" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckLogin" />
</event>
```

In your `Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckLogin.php`

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct(
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
  )
  {
    $this->_customerSession = $session;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
  }

  public function execute(
       \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
  )
  {
      if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           // Customer is logged in 
      } else {
           $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/create');
         return $this;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: i think we need an observer also

Comment: `CheckLogin` is out observer which is catching event and redirecting to registration page

Comment: got it i just saw the code

Comment: okay try and let me know

Comment: no its not working

Comment: check the evet name  try `catalog_category_view_predispatch`